# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, typeerror

I am sure I am missing something somewhere, but I can't see where. I am trying to use the jQuery validate script but get this error continually. I am pretty sure all the files are in the right place etc. This is in the head:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').validate();
}); // end ready
</script>
```

then my form is as follows:

```
  <p>
    <label for="name">Your name:
    </label><br />
    <input name="name" type="text" class="required" title="Please enter your name." id="name" maxlength="80" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="email">Your email address:</label><br /><input name="email" type="text" class="required email" title="Please enter a valid email address." id="email" maxlength="100" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="phone">Your contact number:</label><br />
    <input name="phone" type="text" class="required" title="Please enter your phone number" id="phone" maxlength="50" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="message">Message:<br />
    </label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="form" id="Submit" value="Submit" style="width:100px" />
  </p>

</form>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: First, check your selector is correct -- try `alert($("#form1").serialize())`?

Comment: Is the validate script loading properly?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this - with the 'alert' I get a blank alert box. The validate script is definitely there, but I am not sure how to get the 2 talking...I've used the same scripts previously with no issues.

Comment: I'm also having this exact same problem, when I put the alert suggested by @dbaseman into my ready() function right before the validate call, it does show the form information.  But I'm still getting this error.  My Javascript error console shows that the jquery and validate plugins are loading, and I'm taking this example basically literally from the documentation, but it's failing in this same way.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem and found two issues that caused this:

I accidentally had the jquery reference at the end of the HTML file to speed up loading.  Moving this up above where I was doing the .validate() call resolved that.  Example:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#commentForm').validate();
   });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

I also had a problem where I accidentally loaded the jquery twice, once after the validation load.  Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#commentForm').validate();
   });
</script>
```

This is what I needed to have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#commentForm').validate();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem within a rails project.

My problem was sovled after I deleted the `public/assets` folder, because this caused the project to load the jquery library multiple times (the original one and the precompiled one).